# Homework: solve separable first order ODE: $x' - x^2 = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x' - x^2 = 1$

Thanks for guidelines!

Comment: You won't get much help here unless you show us you have put in some effort. We generally don't enjoy feeling like we are being used to do people's homework. You are even told the ODE is seperable, so have you tried to separate the variables?

Comment: one question : $x=x(?)$

Comment: Do you mean $y'-x^2=1$ ?

Comment: Sorry if you guys felt I wanted you guys to solve it. I just seeked some guidelines. And I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation as

$$ \frac{1}{1+x^2}\cdot x'=1$$

From here it should be easy.

Comment: Thanks! I'm so bad at algebra. Should have seen that...